# Responsiveness / Margin-Left

Tags: html, responsiveness

I would like my image to 'anchor' to the left-side of the screen, so that when I adjust the screen size (specifically from left-to-right), the image keeps the same padding/margin as the background image/overlay.

Currently, the image adjusts only after reaching the very end of the left side of the screen. This is causing the image to appear not centered depending on the size of the screen. (see image for visual)

css

```
.laurel {
  width: 38vw;
  height: auto;
  left: 0%;
  padding-top: 30px;
 }
```

html (using Hugo)
`<img src="{{ .laurel | relURL }}" class="laurel img-responsive" alt="Img"`

[image of issue and desired solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tX64i.png)

Thank you in Advance!

Edit:
The entire code is as follows
HTML

```
<section class="slider-invest {{ if .bg_overlay }}overly-invest{{ 
end }}" style="background-image: url('{{ .bg_image_slider | 
relURL }}');">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="block">
      {{ with .heading }}<h1>{{ . | markdownify }}</h1>{{ end }}
      {{ with .summary1 }}<h3 class="invest-slider-text">{{ . | 
      markdownify }}</h3>{{ end }}
      {{ with .summary2 }}<h3 class="invest-slider-text">{{ . | 
      markdownify }}</h3>{{ end }}
      {{ with .summary3 }}<h3 class="invest-slider-text">{{ . | 
      markdownify }}</h3>{{ end }}
      {{ with .summary4 }}<h3 class="invest-slider-text">{{ . | 
      markdownify }}</h3>{{ end }}
      {{ with .summary5 }}<h3 class="invest-slider-text">{{ . | 
      markdownify }}</h3>{{ end }}
    </div>
    <div>
    <img src="{{ .laurel | relURL }}" class="laurel" alt="Img">
    </div>
    {{ with .button }}
    {{ if .enable }}
    <a href="{{ .link | relLangURL }}" class="btn-invest btn btn- 
    main animated fadeInUp">{{ .label }}</a>
    {{ end }}
    {{ end }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you give a broader context (like css for `.img-responsive`)? Did you review the value of `position` on `.laurel` ancestors?

Comment: hello @user776686, i actually removed .img-responsive as I don't think it was contributing to anything. The entire html & css is above. (I edited to include).